# Suggestion for optimization mysql query

Tags: mysql

Desc:
Complaint_status contains multiple rows for particular complaints,trying to get user wise closed complaint(status=2 and value IN(1,2))

Pain Point:

```
YEAR(cs.created_at)=year(curdate()) 
AND MONTH(cs.created_at)=month(curdate())
```

Taking almost 5 min on local and 1.5 min on server

```
SELECT u3.name,COUNT(c3.id) as closed_tickets
FROM complaint c3,complaint_status cs,assignment a3,user u3
WHERE
c3.id=cs.complaint_id
AND a3.complaint_id=c3.id
AND u3.id=a3.assigned_to
AND u3.user_type=14
AND a3.expiry IS NULL
AND cs.id IN(SELECT MAX(id) FROM complaint_status WHERE complaint_id=c3.id AND status=2 AND value IN(1,2))
AND YEAR(cs.created_at)=year(curdate()) 
AND MONTH(cs.created_at)=month(curdate())
GROUP BY u3.id 
ORDER BY COUNT(c3.id) DESC
```

Comment: Put an explain before this query and edit your question with the results.

Comment: You don`t understand look here http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with applying this predicate in the `WHERE` clause:

```
YEAR(cs.created_at)=year(curdate()) 
AND MONTH(cs.created_at)=month(curdate())
```

Is that MySql needs to evaluate these functions for all records (or at least those remaining). And the waste here is that these are effectively constants, depending on the current date. Assuming that there is an index on `created_at`, you can improve the chances of [hitting the index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), by instead comparing the date to the first day of this month, and less than the first day of next month (and assuming that `created_at` is a DATE):

...

```
   cs.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY),
   AND cs.created_at < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL + 1 DAY)
```

Note that the end date does not include the upper bound (since this could include data on the first second of the following month)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix the `join` status.

Second, instead of:

```
YEAR(cs.created_at) = year(curdate()) AND MONTH(cs.created_at) = month(curdate())
```

Use:

```
cs.created_at >= curdate() and cs_created_at < date_sub(date_sub, curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1, interval 1 month)
```

This will allow the field to use any indexes that have `created_at`.

This appears to be your specific question.

If you really want to optimize the query, I would suggest that ask *another* question with:

- The query rewritten with explicit joins
- The table layouts (or at least existing indexes)
- The explain plan for the query.

Comment: You might be missing some parenthesis in there.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT u3.name,
       COUNT(c3.id) AS closed_tickets
FROM complaint c3
JOIN complaint_status cs
  ON c3.id=cs.complaint_id
JOIN ASSIGNMENT a3
  ON a3.complaint_id=c3.id 
JOIN USER u3
  ON u3.id=a3.assigned_to
JOIN (SELECT complaint_id,
              MAX(id) id
           FROM complaint_status
           WHERE status=2
           AND value IN(1,2)
           GROUP BY complaint_id) cs9
  ON cs9.complaint_id=c3.id
  AND cs.id = cs9.id
WHERE u3.user_type=14
  AND a3.expiry IS NULL    
  AND cs.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY)
  AND cs.created_at < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL + 1 DAY)
GROUP BY u3.id
ORDER BY COUNT(c3.id) DESC
```